Norton's Dome paradox and usage of Newton's 1st law in it
Why in Norton's Dome we dont use Newton's first law as a way of resolution? That is first by using 2nd law we derive the two solutions for the dome. Now we make use of 1st and 3rd law to rule out the "wrong" solution. Since 3rd law doesn't seems to be relevant here, we are left with 1st. Thus, according to it, the only valid solution is $r=0$.
Why doesn't this resolve the paradox?

"Now we make use of 1st and 3rd law to rule out the 'wrong' solution."   How, exactly?

It doesn't matter. It's easy to come up with a variant that does not have zero net force at all, nullifying any argument using the first law.

One side of the paradox is that according to the first law, it should stay at rest.
The other side is that this exact curve has an indeterminant solution where motion could start at any time.
You can resolve the paradox in the sense that it does not arise for objects in the universe. It isn't possible to make this exact curve out of atoms. And if you did, the laws of quantum mechanics would provide a different answer than classical physics. See Can we theoretically balance a perfectly symmetrical pencil on its one-atom tip?

"One side of the paradox is that according to the first law, it should stay at rest."  Newton's first law tells me that any given moment, when there is no force there is no acceleration.  At what moment is this violated?

At no moment. It won't ever move. And that is why the other side, where it can start moving at any time, make up a paradox.

But then "according to the first law, it should stay at rest" is just false.  It's easy to create paradoxes by juxtaposing false statements with true ones:  "One plus one is three, but also one plus one is two!  A paradox!"  But an interesting paradox requires two conflicting statements that at least both appear to be true.

But according to Newtonian mechanics, both are true.

I thought you'd agreed above that the first is false.  Have you changed your mind?  If so, in a solution where the ball moves, what is an example of a moment at which force is zero but acceleration is not?

The paradox is there are many different trajectories that are consistent with the same initial condition. The ball remains stationary until some arbitrary time $t_0$, and then rolls off. Force and acceleration are $0$ until $t_0$, and not afterward.

Up and Atom made a video about this yesterday - The Dome Paradox: A Loophole in Newton's Laws. It's worth watching.
